# how to write a Python program that reads from a text file, and builds a dictionary which maps each word

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I am having difficulties with writing a Python program that reads from a text file, and builds a dictionary which maps each word that appears in the file to a list of all the words that immediately follow that word in the file. The list of words can be in any order and should include duplicates.

For example,the key `"and"` might have the list `["then", "best", "after", ...]` listing all the words which came after `"and"` in the text.

Any idea would be great help.

Comment: Using a `defaultdict(list)` should get you where you want to go, assuming you know how to read a file and iterate through each line.  If you have more specific questions, please revise what you're asking.

Comment: "stuck. I got nothing" - Really? Nothing at all? If you start somewhere (write code that can parse your file ) your question will be more specific and concrete.

Comment: I seems my code helps you. Thank you. I upvote your question though it has nothing particular. But it's to encourage a pythonista !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome on stackoverflow.com

Are you sure you need a dictionary ?
It will takes a lot of memory if the text is long, just to repeat several times the same data for several entries.
While if you use a function, it will give you the desired list(s) at will.
For example:

```
s = """In Newtonian physics, free fall is any motion
of a body where its weight is the only force acting
upon it. In the context of general relativity where
gravitation is reduced to a space-time curvature,
a body in free fall has no force acting on it and
it moves along a geodesic. The present article
concerns itself with free fall in the Newtonian domain."""

import re

def say_me(word,li=re.split('\s+',s)):
    for i,w in enumerate(li):
        if w==word:
            print '\n%s at index %d followed by\n%s' % (w,i,li[i+1:])

say_me('free')
```

result

```
free at index 3 followed by
['fall', 'is', 'any', 'motion', 'of', 'a', 'body', 'where', 'its', 'weight', 'is', 'the', 'only', 'force', 'acting', 'upon', 'it.', 'In', 'the', 'context', 'of', 'general', 'relativity', 'where', 'gravitation', 'is', 'reduced', 'to', 'a', 'space-time', 'curvature,', 'a', 'body', 'in', 'free', 'fall', 'has', 'no', 'force', 'acting', 'on', 'it', 'and', 'it', 'moves', 'along', 'a', 'geodesic.', 'The', 'present', 'article', 'concerns', 'itself', 'with', 'free', 'fall', 'in', 'the', 'Newtonian', 'domain.']

free at index 38 followed by
['fall', 'has', 'no', 'force', 'acting', 'on', 'it', 'and', 'it', 'moves', 'along', 'a', 'geodesic.', 'The', 'present', 'article', 'concerns', 'itself', 'with', 'free', 'fall', 'in', 'the', 'Newtonian', 'domain.']

free at index 58 followed by
['fall', 'in', 'the', 'Newtonian', 'domain.']
```

The assignement `li=re.split('\s+',s)` is a manner to bind the parameter `li` to the object `re.split('\s+',s)` passed as argument.
This binding is done only one time: at the moment where the definition of the function is read by the interpreter to create the function object. It as a parameter defined with a default argument.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ideas:

1. Set up a `collections.defaultdict` for your output. This is a dictionary with a default value for keys that don't yet exist (in this case, as aelfric5578 suggests, an empty `list`);
2. Build a list of all the words in your file, in order; and
3. You can use `zip(lst, lst[1:])` to create pairs of consecutive list elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here was I would do :

```
from collections import defaultdict

# My example line :
s = 'In the face of ambiguity refuse the temptation to guess'

# Previous string is quite easy to tokenize but in real world, you'll have to :
# Remove comma, dot, etc...
# Probably encode to ascii (unidecode 3rd party module can be helpful)
# You'll also probably want to normalize case

lst = s.lower().split(' ')  # naive tokenizer

ddic = defaultdict(list)

for word1, word2 in zip(lst, lst[1:]):
    ddic[word1].append(word2)

# ddic contains what you want (but is a defaultdict)
# if you want to work with "classical" dictionnary, just cast it :
# (Often it's not needed)
dic = dict(ddic)
```

Sorry if I seem to steal commentators ideas, but this is almost the same code that I used in some of my projects (similar document algorithms pre-computation)